# How to call a function when a QObject is about to be destroyed?

Tags: python, destructor, pyqt5, qobject

I'd like to do some cleanup operations inside the object just before its destruction. In this case it would be close the connection to the database.

Here is what I'm already doing:

Worker class:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from pymongo import MongoClient, ASCENDING
from time import sleep

class StatusWidgetWorker(QtCore.QObject):

    ongoing_conversions_transmit = QtCore.pyqtSignal([list])

    def __init__(self, mongo_settings):
        super().__init__()
        print("StatusWidget Worker init")
        mongo_client = MongoClient([mongo_settings["server_address"]])
        self.log_database = mongo_client[mongo_settings["database"]]
        self.ongoing_conversions = mongo_settings["ongoing_conversions"]

    def status_retriever(self):
        print("mongo bridge()")
        while True:
            ongoing_conversions_list = []
            for doc in self.log_database[self.ongoing_conversions].find({}, {'_id': False}).sort([("start_date", ASCENDING)]):
                ongoing_conversions_list.append(doc)
            self.ongoing_conversions_transmit.emit(ongoing_conversions_list)
            sleep(2)
```

And the function that call the worker from an other class :

```
def status_worker(self):
    mongo_settings = "dict parameter"

    self.worker_thread_status = QtCore.QThread()
    self.worker_object_status = StatusWidgetWorker(mongo_settings)
    self.worker_object_status.moveToThread(self.worker_thread_status)

    self.worker_thread_status.started.connect(self.worker_object_status.status_retriever)
    self.worker_object_status.ongoing_conversions_transmit.connect(self.status_table_auto_updater)

    self.worker_thread_status.start()
```

Here is what I already tried:

- [Define a `__del__` function](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python/) in the Worker class, this function is never called.
- Define a function in the Worker class and then connect it to the destroyed signal with `self.destroyed.connect(self.function)`. This function is again never called. I think this happen because the signal is emitted when the object is already destroyed, not before its destruction.

I'm really wondering on how to this, here are some parts of answer:

http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2014-November/035049.html

His approach seems a bit hacky to me (no offense to the author, there is probably no simple answer) and I have signals & parameters to pass to the worker witch would make the ThreadController class messier.

I find this solution a bit hacky because you have to set up a Controller class to do the Worker class job

If nobody has an answer, I'll probably use the ThreadController class and post the result here.

thank you for reading :-)

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is to connect to the [`QObject.destroyed`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal. I'm not understanding why you consider that solution "hacky". Could you elaborate?

Comment: edited my question, it should be clear now

Comment: Hmm, did you try connecting the destroyed signal to a slot in the thread itself, or one in the main thread?

Comment: I tried to connect it to a slot in the thread itself because I want to close the db connection that this thread opened.

Comment: I'm still a bit surprised that didn't work. One last question, did you make the connection to the destroyed signal in the `__init__` method, or the `status_retriever` method? The former will make the connection in the main thread, while the latter should make the connection in the thread itself. I would not be surprised if the thread was destroyed by the time a signal was processed by the main thread, but signals should be processed immediately if they are calling a slot in the same thread and that signal should be emitted before the object is destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual rule in python apply:

> there is a module for that

the solution is to use the atexit module and register the cleanup function in the `__init__` function.

Example:

```
import atexit

class StatusWidgetWorker(QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # code here
        atexit.register(self.cleanup)

    def cleanup(self):
        print("Doing some long cleanup")
        sleep(2)
        self.bla = "Done !"
        print(self.bla)
```